# How can I reference OS Env in Spring config properties?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, docker

I run a project in a Docker container and I want to set project properties (which are set in the `application.properties` file) into the OS Env.

For example, `M2_HOME` is an OS Env, now I need to use it in spring config properties like `m2_home=${M2_HOME}`, so I can use `m2_home` in my project.

I have tried to config like:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath*:/resource/application-${profiles.active}.properties</value>
    </property>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but it doesn't work. What can I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Please put code snippet instead of screenshot.

Comment: It always remind me the code snippet style is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've been there for quite a few times: setting up a Docker image for a project and having to support [not so] legacy apps with text based config files.

Confd (https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd) served me well, but it's a little bit of an overkill for such a trivial task. Confd is rather geared towards fetching configuration from clustered KV-stores, hence it takes a little bit too much of a ceremony.

So I ended up making something way simpler: Templater (https://github.com/reertech/templater). You can download a standalone binary with no dependencies and use it right off the bat. When you run it it takes the Go template (here's a quick reference on the language https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and processes it into the output file allowing you to substitute computed values and fetch environment variables.

Hope this helps if not you, then at least some future wanderer!